# Is thermoelectric cooler needed to produce constant laser output?

Tags: laser

I'm making a laser diode module using a LD, a PD, and a LD driver board. With the components I would be able to monitor the optical output from the LD and then adjust current to keep the output constant. However, I wonder if I also need a TEC. The ambient temperature of my device would change fast (1℃/1min). Wouldn't it be enough to adjust the power using the PD and a LD driver IC? The temperature would not exceed the operating temperature range.

Comment: Electrical control of forward current is several orders of magnitude faster than any thermal control can be. 1°C/min isn't fast though and can be compensated by a TEC. You really only need a TEC if you need wavelength stability (to a high enough degree) or the system generates more heat than its surface can dissipate naturally through un-aided contact or convection.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the duty cycle. You should be ok with a heatsink and fan to dissipate the heat but if the duty cycle will be high you might uss a TEC just to be safe. I would always use a heatsink with a laser diode no matter what the duty cycle is.